# Update Vue data value after async fucntion call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuejs2, async-await

I have an Vue app that has text object and need to update it after api call.

Currently  I have resolve this by:

```
      document.querySelector("#text").textContent = result.quote;
```

inside timeout function after successful resolve

But i really need to learn how to make it work by binding outside value to Vue app in async way.

```
  var textEl = new Vue({
    el: "#text",
    data: {
      text: //here,
    },
  });
```

...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h3 class="margin" id="text"></h3>
  <script>
    const api = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6080dabc56c62a0c0e8a1bcf";

    async function radnomQuote() {
      return await fetch(api)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
          return res.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * res.quotes.length)];
        });
    }

    async function asyncGuote() {
      const result = await radnomQuote();
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("#text").textContent = result.quote;
      }, 500);
    }

    var textEl = new Vue({
      el: "#text",
      data: {
        text: "",
      },
      created() {
        asyncGuote();
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried numerous things like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 class="margin" id="text"></h3>
  <script>
    const api = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6080dabc56c62a0c0e8a1bcf";

    async function radnomQuote() {
      return await fetch(api)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
          return res.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * res.quotes.length)];
        });
    }
    let txt
    async function asyncGuote() {
      const result = await radnomQuote();
      setTimeout(function() {
        return txt = result.quote;
      }, 500);
    }

    var textEl = new Vue({
      el: "#text",
      data: {
        text: txt,
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h3 class="margin" id="text"></h3>
  <script>
    const api = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6080dabc56c62a0c0e8a1bcf";

    async function radnomQuote() {
      return await fetch(api)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((res) => {
          return res.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * res.quotes.length)];
        });
    }
    let txt
    async function asyncGuote() {
      const result = await radnomQuote();
      setTimeout(function() {
       txt = result.quote
        return txt;
      }, 500);
    }

    var textEl = new Vue({
      el: "#text",
      data: {
        text: asyncGuote(),
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have read about Computed Properties and Watchers but I don't understand them yet or that is not what I am looking for.

The whole project of random quote in vue is here: https://codepen.io/ikiK_Cro/pen/ZELmgeP , and I really don't like that i fetch elements by `querySelector` inside `async` function wile I have defined Vue apps. I feel like there has to be a way to update app itself, something like observable objects in nativeScript that watches for changes of value inside.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I left out element binding in element...

```
 <h3 class="margin" id="text">{{text}}</h3>
```

Than I can access and change value inside function by targeting apps field:

```
textEl.text=result.quote;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using async, await syntax properly. when you use async and await you don't need to use .then() - it is the replacement to .then(), just a different syntax.

You also need to use vue properly. all your functions need to be at the `methods` section of the vue instance.

I would recommend working with a project you open using `@vue/cli` [follow this docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create) and once you have you can use the code below:

```js
<template>
  <h3 class="margin" id="text"> {{ text }}</h3>
</template>

  <script>
    // here include all you imports

    const api = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6080dabc56c62a0c0e8a1bcf";

    export default {
      data(){
         return  {
            text: "",
         }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.asyncGuote();
      },
      methods: {
         async function radnomQuote() {
            let response = await fetch(api);
            response = await response.json();
            return response.quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * response.quotes.length)];
         },
         async function asyncGuote() {
            const result = await this.radnomQuote();
            setTimeout(function() {
               this.text = result.quote;
            }, 500);
         }
      }
   };
  </script>
```

Comment: I know I can change value from inside app, I was looking for a way to update it from outside.

Comment: oh ok so this answer is not relevant i guess

Comment: "all your functions need to be at the methods section of the vue instance."  No, i need one function outside to update multipe apps. I dont want to repeat it for every app i have. Goal is to update multiple with one async call from outside. But thanks for anwser. I solved it with my anwser. From inside app I will do additional logic based on value received.